# CSS class not styling element

Tags: html, css

In a website I've been working on lately I have a div that's been causing problems. All my attempts at styling it have been completely ignored.

The element:

```
<div class="egg">
  <p class="egg">Hi there! You have successfully found the Easter Egg. Here's your reward: </p>
  <p class="egg">By the way, here's a pro tip: don't ever say <strike>"monkey"</strike> the "M" word around Orangutans. They <i>really</i> don't like it.</p>
</div>
```

The styling I'm attempting to apply:

```
.egg {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

p.egg {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

When rendered the div and its contents remains obstinately unstyled, with the exception of a `color` inherited from its parent `body`.

How do I make the styling render correctly?

EDIT: Yes, I have imported the Josefin Sans font. It's working elsewhere in the webpage.

EDIT2: Several

```js
// The behind-the-scenes work.

let darkMode = false;
let last_keypresses = [0];
let konami_code = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65] // For some reason the repeated up arrow doesn't register.

const titleText = $(".standardname");
const sciText = $(".sciname");

const rawStdName = titleText.text().split("");
const rawSciName = sciText.text().split("");

titleText.text("");
sciText.text("");

let curchar = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 150);

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    last_keypresses.push(e.keyCode || e.which);

    if (last_keypresses.length > konami_code.length) {
      last_keypresses.shift();
    }

    if (JSON.stringify(last_keypresses) === JSON.stringify(konami_code)) {
      console.log("Easter Egg!");
      $("#egg").show({
        "margin-left": "auto",
        "display": "block"
      }, "fast")
    }
  })


});

for (let i = 0; i < rawStdName.length; i++) {
  titleText.html(titleText.html() + "<span>" + rawStdName[i] + "</span>");

  if (i < rawSciName.length) {
    sciText.html(sciText.html() + "<span>" + rawSciName[i] + "</span>");
  }
}



async function onTick() {
  $(".standardname").children("span").eq(curchar).addClass("animated");

  if (curchar < rawSciName.length) {
    $(".sciname").children("span").eq(curchar).addClass("animated");
  }

  curchar++;
  if (curchar === rawStdName.length) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
}

function complete() {
  console.log("Title animation completed.")
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}


function toggleDarkMode() {
  // Toggle dark mode

  toggle = $(".dark-mode-toggle");
  root = $("#root");

  toggle.toggleClass("dark");

  switch (darkMode) {
    case false:
      toggle.text("Light mode");
      root.toggleClass("background_svg");
      root.toggleClass("dark");
      darkMode = true;
      break;

    case true:
      toggle.text("Dark mode");
      root.toggleClass("dark");
      root.toggleClass("background_svg");
      darkMode = false;
      break;
  }

  $("body").toggleClass("dark");
  $("#the-genuine-article").toggleClass("dark");

  let links = $(".info-link");
  for (let index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
    links.eq(index).toggleClass("dark");
  }
}

function changeSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = $(".mySlides");

  if (n > slides.length) slideIndex = 1;
  if (n < 1) slideIndex = slides.length;

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides.eq(i).css("display", "none");
  }

  slides.eq(slideIndex - 1).css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  /* Required for the parallax to work */
  transition: background-color 1s, background-image 1s;
}

html.background_svg {
  background-color: #bbaa99;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='400' height='200' viewBox='0 0 160 80'%3E%3Cg fill='%23B0A090' %3E%3Cpolygon points='0 10 0 0 10 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 40 0 30 10 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 30 0 20 10 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 70 0 60 10 60'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 80 0 70 10 70'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='50 80 50 70 60 70'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='10 20 10 10 20 10'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='10 40 10 30 20 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='20 10 20 0 30 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='10 10 10 0 20 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30 20 30 10 40 10'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='20 20 20 40 40 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='40 10 40 0 50 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='40 20 40 10 50 10'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='40 40 40 30 50 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30 40 30 30 40 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='40 60 40 50 50 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='50 30 50 20 60 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='40 60 40 80 60 60'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='50 40 50 60 70 40'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='60 0 60 20 80 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='70 30 70 20 80 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='70 40 70 30 80 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='60 60 60 80 80 60'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='80 10 80 0 90 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='70 40 70 60 90 40'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='80 60 80 50 90 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='60 30 60 20 70 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='80 70 80 80 90 80 100 70'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='80 10 80 40 110 10'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='110 40 110 30 120 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='90 40 90 70 120 40'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='10 50 10 80 40 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='110 60 110 50 120 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='100 60 100 80 120 60'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='110 0 110 20 130 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='120 30 120 20 130 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='130 10 130 0 140 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='130 30 130 20 140 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='120 40 120 30 130 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='130 50 130 40 140 40'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='120 50 120 70 140 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='110 70 110 80 130 80 140 70'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 10 140 0 150 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 20 140 10 150 10'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 40 140 30 150 30'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 50 140 40 150 40'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 70 140 60 150 60'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='150 20 150 40 160 30 160 20'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='150 60 150 50 160 50'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='140 70 140 80 150 80 160 70'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  transition: color 1s;
}

.info-link:link {
  color: darkslategrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-link:visited {
  color: darkslategrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-link:hover {
  color: darkslategrey;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: text-decoration 1s;
}

.info-link.dark:link {
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.info-link.dark:visited {
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.info-link.dark:hover {
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: rgb(121, 113, 11)
}

body {
  color: black;
  transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615982513414-d287e6b70ad6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1052&q=80);
  /* Photo by CHUTTERSNAP on Unsplash. */
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#the-genuine-article {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  transition: color 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#the-genuine-article.dark {
  color: cornsilk;
}

.dark-mode-toggle {
  font: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

.light {
  color: black;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
  color: cornsilk;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1cm;
  margin-top: 1cm;
  padding-top: 1px;
  /* Placeholder pad to ensure that #titlestuff is aligned correctly. */
}

#titlestuff {
  background-color: rgba(255, 248, 220, 0.4);
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 3;
}

.standardname {
  font-family: "Limelight", cursive;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.sciname {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

article {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: larger;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 466px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

br {
  margin-top: 1cm;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 466px;
}

span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

span.animated {
  opacity: 1;
}

.egg {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p.egg {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="root" class="background_svg">

<head>
  <!-- Image Credits: 
      - Slideshow images: Wikimedia
      - Parallax Background: Unsplash
      - Favicon: favicon.io
    -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Orangutan - Prendapolis Zoo</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
  </nav>

  <div class="egg">
    <p class="egg">Hi there! You have successfully found the easter egg. Here's your reward: </p>
    <p class="egg">By the way, here's a pro tip: don't ever say <strike>"monkey"</strike> the "M" word around Orangutans. They <i>really</i> don't like it.</p>
  </div>

  <header class="parallax light">
    <div id="titlestuff">
      <h1 class="standardname">Bornean Orangutan</h1>
      <i class="sciname">Pongo Pygmaeus</i>
    </div>
  </header>

  <article class="light" id="the-genuine-article">
    <p>
      Native to the lush rainforests of Borneo, the Bornean Orangutan is one of the only surviving species of the Ponginae family. Among the most intelligent primates, they are known for using complex tools and constructing sleeping shelters.
    </p>

    <p>
      Although they are best known for their red fur and large cheek pads, the latter are only present in the males. Females do not have them, and are much smaller than the males (a phenomena known as sexual dimorphism.)
    </p>

    <p>
      Their diet consists primarily of fruit, but they are known to also occasionally eat leaves, nuts, bark, and small animals. Unlike most great apes they have a high resistance to strychnine. As a result, they have become the sole fruit disperser for the
      vine <i>Strychnos Ignatii.</i>
    </p>

    <p>
      Orangutans are the least social great ape. Females and their immature offspring live together in small groups, usually staying within a defined home range. Once they reach maturity males leave their mother and establish a home range including several
      females. While males' territory may sometimes overlap, they generally avoid each other. Unlike other great apes, Orangutans generally do not practice social grooming.
    </p>

    <p>
      Despite extensive conservation efforts the Bornean Orangutan is critically endangered, with an estimated population of 104,700. This is primarily due to logging, which has reduced their habitat by 55% over the past twenty years. Many are also killed by
      hunting. Although the latter has been somewhat reduced by their endangered status, their numbers continue to decline. To find out how you can help, go to <a class="info-link" href="https://www.worldwildlife.org/species/bornean-orangutan">https://www.worldwildlife.org/species/bornean-orangutan</a>.
    </p>

    <p>
      For more information about the Bornean Orangutan, see <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornean_orangutan" class="info-link">here</a>.
    </p>
  </article>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Orangutan-Columbus-zoo.JPG/640px-Orangutan-Columbus-zoo.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="A mature male Orangutan" />
      <div class="text">A mature male</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Orangutan_-_Sepilok_Sanctuary_Center_-_Sabah_-_Borneo_-_Malaysia_-_panoramio_-_diego_cue.jpg/640px-Orangutan_-_Sepilok_Sanctuary_Center_-_Sabah_-_Borneo_-_Malaysia_-_panoramio_-_diego_cue.jpg"
      />
      <div class="text">A female</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Orangutan_Chillin.jpg/640px-Orangutan_Chillin.jpg" />
      <div class="text">A juvenile</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="changeSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="changeSlide(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <footer>
    <button onclick="toggleDarkMode()" class="dark dark-mode-toggle" id="toggle">Dark mode </button>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

It's working in the snippet, but not when I open the webpage in Firefox. Is there some kind of compatibility issue happening?

Comment: How are you linking the stylesheet / styles to the page? Please post a fully-reproducible example.

Comment: *It's working elsewhere in the webpage* --> then your code here is not the minimalistic one to reproduct the issue, you have for usre more CSS involved

Comment: Have a look in your browser's devtools at the p elements to see what exactly is styling them if it isn't the CSS you have given you say.

Comment: @AHaworth The only things that are being inherited is `color: black` (from the body element) and `box-sizing: border-box` (which is applied to everything)

Comment: And are you seeing that the egg class is in the styling list? Also why have you got .egg as visibility: hidden? You need to make a [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as the code in your question 'works' (if you take out the hidden).

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure this is the actual order of your css styles, because the later will override the first.

If you want to make sure something gets applied you can also use `!important` but in your code, that should not change something.

Also note that your `p.egg` also has all non-overwritten css styles from `.egg`, so you do not need to add again stuff like `max-width`,`margin` and `text-align` but you **should** overwrite your `visibility:hidden`

Apart from that your code seems to be working perfectly so you should either include more of your code, as there may be something else overwritting your styles.

Answer (score -1):

Good morning, please try to use `!important` after the propriety

Example:

> color: 'blue' !important;

Comment: I have already tried that. It remains unstyled.